# Reimplemented copy() slot in PyQt for QTextBrowser Never been Called

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm going to replace some content in QTextBroswer before they pushed to clipboard. So I should reimplement `copy()`. But, PyQt doesn't call my overloaded method. What's wrong?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Label(QtGui.QTextBrowser):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def copy(self):
        # Never been called.
        print("Called")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTextBrowser.copy() is a slot not a virtual function, so you have to be careful to reimplement it.
Please have a look at [this](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/is_it_possible_to_reimplement_non-virtual_slots) post, this may help you.